# Airflow: PythonOperator: why to include 'ds' arg?

Tags: airflow

While defining a function to be later used as a python_callable, why is 'ds' included as the first arg of the function?

For example:

```
def python_func(ds, **kwargs):
    pass
```

I looked into the Airflow documentation, but could not find any explanation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is related to the `provide_context=True` parameter. As per Airflow documentation,

> if set to true, Airflow will pass a set of keyword arguments that can be used in your function. This set of kwargs correspond exactly to what you can use in your jinja templates. For this to work, you need to define **kwargs in your function header.

`ds` is one of these keyword arguments and represents execution date in format "YYYY-MM-DD". For parameters that are marked as (templated) in the documentation, you can use `'{{ ds }}'` default variable to pass the execution date. You can read more about default variables here:

https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/code.html?highlight=pythonoperator#default-variables (obsolete)

https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=python_callable

PythonOperator doesn't have templated parameters, so doing something like

```
python_callable=print_execution_date('{{ ds }}')
```

won't work. To print execution date inside the callable function of your PythonOperator, you will have to do it as

```
def print_execution_date(ds, **kwargs):
    print(ds)
```

or

```
def print_execution_date(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs.get('ds'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you define your function like `def something(**kwargs)` then you get an error "unexpected keyword argument 'dag' passed to python_callable(*op_args, **op_kwargs)" so it seems like you need to have something else, I don't really understand it, but using any of those keyword params before **kwargs seems to work.